# Showing number of rows updated and inserting from Excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to display the values of rows inserted and updated seperately. I am using PHPExcel to upload the file on my server and read rows to insert or update values in the database. I currently have a file of 4500 rows, but the variable always end up being 0. (Codeigniter)

Model

//get values

```
function fi_upload($file_name){
$file = './uploads/'.$file_name;


$this->load->library('excel');

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

$cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();

    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
        $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
        $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
        if ($row == 1) {
            $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }else{
            $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }
    }

    $data['header'] = $header;
    $data['values'] = $arr_data;
    $insert =0;
$update =0;
$crinsert =0;
$crupdate=0;

foreach ($arr_data as $q){

        if($q['A']==NULL){
        continue;
        }else{

            $data = array(
                //insert columns and values
                );

            if($q['G']=="CR"){

                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where('ledger_cust',$q['A']);
                $this->db->where('ledger_date',$insertLedgerDate);
                $this->db->where('ledger_assign',$q['D']);
                $this->db->where('ledger_cr_post',$q['O']);
                $query = $this->db->get('tbl_ledger');
                if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_cust',$q['A']);
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_date',$insertLedgerDate);
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_assign',$q['D']);
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_cr_post',$q['O']);
                                    $this->db->update('tbl_ledger',$data);
                                    $crupdate++;

                                    }else{
                                     $this->db->insert('tbl_ledger',$data);
                                     $crinsert++;

                                    }

              }else{
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where('ledger_cust',$q['A']);
                $this->db->where('ledger_doc_no',$q['H']);
                $this->db->where('ledger_balance',$q['P']);

                $query2 = $this->db->get('tbl_ledger');
                            if($query2->num_rows() > 0){
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_cust',$q['A']);
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_doc_no',$q['H']);
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_balance',$q['P']);
                                    $this->db->where('ledger_db_post',$q['N']);
                                    $this->db->update('tbl_ledger',$data);
                                    $update++;
                                  }else{
                                 $this->db->insert('tbl_ledger',$data);
                                 $insert++;
                                 }
                    }
                }
}
$insert = $insert + $crinsert;

$update = $update + $crupdate;

echo $insert;
echo "<br>";
echo $update;
$msg = "Ledger Successfully Uploaded. <br> New Entries  ".$insert." <br>Updated Entries ".$update;
return $msg;
}
```

If the number of rows are low, it successfully shows the value. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$insert` `$crinsert` `$update` `$crupdate` are not defined in that code.

Comment: Do You see that html at all? May memory usage be too big and thus crashing script?

Comment: Nope. all the data is entered into the database. and it just shows the msg but both update and insert variables are 0.

also I am initializing the variables.. forgot to enter that code here. editing